# How do I get the mac address or IPAddress from a cisco callmanager?

Tags: .net, vb.net, cisco

Is there any way to retrieve either the mac address or the IP address of phones on a Cisco server using Callmanager version 6 via the axl with VB.net?

The server can retrieve the IP address itself to use the phone and it's not in the database information retrieved from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the WSDL file from your CallManager server.  Then with the included methods, you can make a call to getPhone and it's pretty simple from there.  If you want to do it in a more manual way, you can use the method from this blog post:

http://blog.crowe.co.nz/Archive/2008/October

(See the section "Getting the IP Addresses of Phones from a Cisco Call Manager v6.x using C#")